# From series to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello good night everyone, I have a doubt.

It is possible to convert a vector (pandas series) of days of the week into a dictionary such that the value of how many days of the week is in the vector is accounted for.

Something like {'Monday': 4, 'Tuesday': 5 ... 'Friday': 8}

Where the days of the week are the key and its frequency the value.

Comment: `your_series.value_counts()`...

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

example df:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'day':['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri']})

     day
0    Mon
1   Tues
2    Wed
3  Thurs
4    Fri

counts = d['day'].value_counts()
d = {key:val for key,val in zip(counts.index,counts.values)}
```

result:

```
{'Tues': 1, 'Fri': 1, 'Thurs': 1, 'Wed': 1, 'Mon': 1}
```

Comment: ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only